# Critical exponents inequalities - Landau Ginzburg theory of phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

By studying the **Landau Ginzburg theory of phase transition**, I have heard (but couldn't find) that there is a topic related to that, called "**critical exponents inequalities**".

I am familiar with critical exponents equalities, but having trouble finding articles on the inequalities.

Does anyone have some academic material  or suggestions on this topic?

Comment: The relevant literature is in mathematical physics. See in particular Ch 14 of the book "Random Walks, Critical Phenomena, and Triviality in Quantum Field Theory" by Fernandez, Frohlich and Sokal https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ferna107/papers/root.pdf

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you very much. do you know why I can't see the figures in the relevant chapter?

Comment: This is a free preliminary version on one of the authors' webpage. For the figures you would need the final published version https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662028681